# Python Flask unable to set content-length

Tags: python, web-services, flask

Im creating a quick RESTful service using Python & Flask in order to externalize configuration data and call the configuration on app start.

Initially my server side code was:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)


# this endpint returns backend server  connection settings
@app.route('/config/server_config/<string:customer_name>',
           methods=['GET'])
def get_config_server_config(customer_name):
    if customer_name == 'grant':
        return (jsonify([{
            'address': 'aaa.bb.cc.dd',
            'comm_hub_address': '192.168.137.38',
            'comm_hub_udp_beacon': '192.168.42.129',
            'comm_hub_port': '50000',
            'mqtt_port': '1883',
            'rest_port': '8000',
            'chat_port': '8010',
            }]), 200)
    if customer_name == 'orange':
        return (jsonify([{
            'address': 'aaa.bb.cc.dd',
            'comm_hub_address': '192.168.137.38',
            'comm_hub_udp_beacon': '192.168.42.129',
            'comm_hub_port': '50000',
            'mqtt_port': '1883',
            'rest_port': '8000',
            'chat_port': '8010',
            }]), 200)
    if customer_name == 'blue':
        return (jsonify([{
            'address': 'aaa.bb.cc.dd',
            'comm_hub_address': '192.168.137.38',
            'comm_hub_udp_beacon': '192.168.42.129',
            'comm_hub_port': '50000',
            'mqtt_port': '1883',
            'rest_port': '8000',
            'chat_port': '8010',
            }]), 200)
    else:
        return (jsonify({'error': 'customer does not exist'}), 404)

#if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**The JSON was being returned correctly:**

[[{"address":"137.78.81.53","chat_port":"8010","comm_hub_address":"192.168.137.38","comm_hub_port":"50000","comm_hub_udp_beacon":"192.168.42.129","mqtt_port":"1883","rest_port":"8000"}],200]

However...

The issue was my client side Android would through EOFException complaining that the Content-Length as 0

**Therefore I attempted to set the content length on Python side since it was not being set explicitly:**

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
    app = Flask(__name__)


    # this endpint returns backend server  connection settings
    @app.route('/config/server_config/<string:customer_name>',
               methods=['GET'])
    def get_config_server_config(customer_name):
        if customer_name == 'grant':
            # set response object & return with http code
            resp = Flask.make_response(jsonify([{
                    'address': 'aaa.bb.cc.dd',
                    'chat_port': '8010',
                    'comm_hub_address': '192.168.137.38',
                    'comm_hub_port': '50000',
                    'comm_hub_udp_beacon': '192.168.42.129',
                    'mqtt_port': '1883',
                    'rest_port': '8000',
                    }]), 200)
            resp.mimetype = 'application/json'
            #set content length
            resp.headers['Content-Length'] = len(resp.get_data())
            return resp
        if customer_name == 'harris':
            return (jsonify([{
                'address': 'aaa.bb.cc.dd',
                'comm_hub_address': '192.168.137.38',
                'comm_hub_udp_beacon': '192.168.42.129',
                'comm_hub_port': '50000',
                'mqtt_port': '1883',
                'rest_port': '8000',
                'chat_port': '8010',
                }]), 200)
        if customer_name == 'hastings':
            return (jsonify([{
                'address': 'aaa.bb.cc.dd',
                'comm_hub_address': '192.168.137.38',
                'comm_hub_udp_beacon': '192.168.42.129',
                'comm_hub_port': '50000',
                'mqtt_port': '1883',
                'rest_port': '8000',
                'chat_port': '8010',
                }]), 200)
        else:
            return (jsonify({'error': 'customer does not exist'}), 404)

    #if __name__ == '__main__':
        #app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

However in the browser Im getting an error:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

and in the logs & command line window im getting

AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'response_class'
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2018 13:08:44] "GET /config/server_config/grant HTTP/1.1" 500 -

**How can i set the content-length of a response object using the Flask package?**

Thanks